# Meaning of notation $Fr$ in topology

Tags: general-topology

I have a homework to finish in distance learning. In one question I'm facing an unknown notation:

Let $I=\left[0;1\right]$, then what is $Fr(I^2)$. What does the "$Fr$" notation stands for?

Sorry if the question is trivial. But is is hard to google "Fr" or "Fr topology" and get meaningful results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means "boundary", from French "frontière".

Comment: Thanks. I actually am French and I did not even think about it...

Comment: and in English, "frontier" :)

Comment: I thought that in English it could be fringe. Prob'ly not, tho'.:)